# apache mpm worker run only single process

Tags: python, django, apache, process

I need to make apache mpm worker use only a single process to run my django server .

I have a view which needs to be run only once when the first request hits the apache . But i see it running twice. I made the runprocess configuration from 2 to 1 .

what else should i do to make apache run only one process..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative could be to use something like mod_wsgi in daemon mode configured with only one process, then hand off to that.

This is all assuming that your web server only ever needs to be single process, and that no other request should be served in parallel? Do you have other views which aren't rate limited? In which case, you could do this via some sort of lock file for this view only, rather than trying to make the web server single process?

Comment: how do u lock the file for just one view ?